# why is my TreeMap moving a key beginning with 'A' to the end of the keyValueSet?

Tags: java

I am currently making a method that returns a `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>` that holds `definitions(key=term,value=definition)`.

For some reason, after I have created the method, it puts a term that begins with `A` at the end of the `keySet`. I thought that `TreeMap`s where in a sorted order? It is just the first item all the others are in order.

Really annoying me as I can't see where my bug is.

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Create new object
    FileParser fp = new FileParser();

    //call to method
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> output = fp.createGlossary("glossary.txt");

    //print output
    for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> entry : output.entrySet()) 
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
    }
}
```

Method:

```
public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> createGlossary(String fileName)
{
    //Local variables that are equal to a parsed file of terms and definitions
    ArrayList<String> termList = this.parseTerms(fileName);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> defList = this.parsedDefinitions(this.rawDefinitions(fileName));

    //Map to to hold above variables
    Map<String, ArrayList<String >> glossary = new TreeMap<>();

    //Iterators to loop through the terms and definitions
    Iterator<String> termIterator = termList.iterator();
    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> defIterator = defList.iterator();
    System.out.println(glossary);


    //As both terms and definitions are the same length iterate until both are exhausted
    while(termIterator.hasNext() && defIterator.hasNext())
    {
        //put key-value pair using term as the key and definition as the value.
        String key = termIterator.next().toUpperCase();
        ArrayList<String> value = defIterator.next();
        glossary.put(key, value);
    }
    return glossary;
}
```

Output of first and last item:

```
//First Item in Map
ABSTRACT CLASS => [A, class, that, defines, a, common, message, protocol, and, common, set, of, instance, variables, for, its, subclasses., In, Java, an, abstract, class, cannot, be, instantiated.]

//Some K-V pairs from middle
SIGNATURE  => [See, method, signature.]
SOFTWARE => [A, general, term, for, all, programs, that, can, be, run, on, a, desktop, computer, or, another, hardware, platform,, such, as, a, mobile, phone.]
SOFTWARE COMPONENT => [A, piece, of, software, that, can, be, readily, combined, with, other, components, to, construct, more, complex, software.]
SORTED COLLECTION => [A, collection, that, always, keeps, its, elements, in, their, natural, ordering,, if, any., This, contrasts, with, an, ordered, collection,, where, the, ordering, may, just, be, an, accident, of, where, elements, happen, to, have, been, placed, in, the, collection.]
SOURCE CODE => [Program, text, expressed, in, a, high-level, programming, language.]
STABLE SORT => [A, sort, that, does, not, reorder, equal, elements.]

//Last Item in Map
ABSOLUTE PATHNAME => [A, full, path, to, a, file, beginning, from, the, name, of, the, storage, device.]
```

I didn't copy all of it as there are hundreds of lines. However, everything else is in order?

It's almost like its pushing ABSOLUTE PATHNAME to the end of the map?

Edit: After reading comment I have included class so maybe a recreation can be made...
The method readFileIn() simply reads each line one at a time...if the line is an even number there is a definition if the line is an odd number its a term...Hope that enough to recreate bug. Sorry for the un-commented code dump.

Thanks again.
Paul

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class FileParser 
{

private int numberOfTerms;

public void setNumberOfTerms(int numberOfTerms) { this.numberOfTerms = numberOfTerms; }

public ArrayList<String> readFileIn(String fileName)
{
    File file = new File(fileName);
    StringBuilder parsedFile = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        Scanner glossaryTXTFile = new Scanner(file);

        while (glossaryTXTFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = glossaryTXTFile.nextLine();
            parsedFile.append(line);
            parsedFile.append("\n");

        }
        glossaryTXTFile.close();
        parsedFile.setLength(parsedFile.length() - 1);

        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(parsedFile.toString().split("\n")));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found, please check the path and make sure extension is included.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> rawDefinitions(String fileName)
{
    ArrayList<String> definitions = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 1;
    for(String holder : this.readFileIn(fileName))
    {
        if(counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            definitions.add(holder);
        }
        counter++;
    }

    return definitions;
}
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parsedDefinitions(ArrayList<String> sentence)
{

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> choppedSentences = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String words : sentence)
    {
        String[] splitSentences = words.split(" ");
        choppedSentences.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(splitSentences)));
    }
    this.setNumberOfTerms(choppedSentences.size());
    return choppedSentences;
}
public ArrayList<String> parseTerms(String fileName)
{
    ArrayList<String> terms = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 1;
    for(String holder : this.readFileIn(fileName))
    {
        if(counter % 2 != 0)
        {
            terms.add(holder);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return terms;
}
public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> createGlossary(String fileName)
{
    //Local variables that are equal to a parsed file of terms and definitions
    ArrayList<String> termList = this.parseTerms(fileName);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> defList = this.parsedDefinitions(this.rawDefinitions(fileName));

    //Map to to hold above variables
    Map<String, ArrayList<String >> glossary = new TreeMap<>();

    //Iterators to loop through the terms and definitions
    Iterator<String> termIterator = termList.iterator();
    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> defIterator = defList.iterator();
    System.out.println(glossary);


    //As both terms and definitions are the same length iterate until both are exhausted
    while(termIterator.hasNext() && defIterator.hasNext())
    {
        //put key-value pair using term as the key and definition as the value.
        String key = termIterator.next().toUpperCase();
        ArrayList<String> value = defIterator.next();
        glossary.put(key, value);
    }
    return glossary;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Create new object
    FileParser fp = new FileParser();

    //call to method
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> output = fp.createGlossary("glossary.txt");

    //print output
    for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> entry : output.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's only one print in this code, and it's going to print an empty map.  Where is your output coming from?

Comment: main sorry ill include...two seconds...

Comment: _its almost like its pushing ABSOLUTE PATHNAME to the end of the map?_ Why do you think it shouldn't be the last element? Can you show us other entries which should not be added before concerned entry?

Comment: 'A' is capital and has a bigger value than 'z' (lowercase)

Comment: 2 words: Case sensitive.

Comment: @Serge Note : `termIterator.next().toUpperCase()` So all keys are in upper case.

Comment: I have cast all toUpperCase

Comment: So what's immediately before `ABSOLUTE PATHNAME`?

Comment: @coder-croc it shouldnt be last element it should be first as its a sortedMap or at least I thought that what a TreeMap provided. I will grab some more output and put into above

Comment: @xiaofeng.li                                                                                          
ZERO-BASED INDEXING => [An, indexing, system, in, which, the, first, index, is, 0.] all other values in order except one im on about.

Comment: Please read the instructions about how to ask a question and especially the part about [providing a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You'll get more useful answers.

Comment: Really sorry Gene, I will add the other methods now.

Comment: Possibly you are dealing with invisible unicode characters or symbols that looks like English letters. Assuming you are copying the output directly, it's more likely an invisible character.

Comment: @xiaofeng.li - thanks as well, it was a hidden header character &f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the code, I am sure your text file has some invisible character which is creating problem in `Treemap` sorting.

Consider following example,

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        treeMap.put("ABSTRACT CLASS", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        treeMap.put("\u200eABSOLUTE PATHNAME", Arrays.asList(11, 22, 33, 44));

        for (Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ABSTRACT CLASS=[1, 2, 3, 4]
‎ABSOLUTE PATHNAME=[11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Make sure that your text file has correct content. To check invisible characters you can use Notepad++, just open file and enable *View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters*.

Comment: Thanks so much....Turns out that it wasnt showing on hidden charcters...as I did with notepad.exe there was a hidden header &f...now working perfect...saved my life :)